# CSS - first-child selector stronger than class selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to fire a CSS animation by adding a class to an list element that is styled by a first-child selector. But somehow the current style is not overwritten by the added class.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsAZQ/8/)

HTML

```
<ul class="start">
<li id="box" >move up onHover</li>
</ul>
<div id="button">hover</div>
```

CSS

```
.start li:first-child{

height:100px;
width:100px;
background: red;
opacity: 1;
transform: translate(0, 190px); 
transition: all 2.0s linear;

}

.change{
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translate(0, 0px);
 }

#button{
width: 80px;
height: 20px;
padding: 4px;
margin-left: 333px;
border:solid 1px black;
background: grey;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
}
```

JS

```
    $('#button').hover(function() {
  $('#box').addClass('change');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that it's stronger, but targeting the parent and then the LI is more specific, so you have to be just as specific when adding a new class

```
.start li.change
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsAZQ/10/)

Comment: thank you, but that is also bad to use "li.class" I read on stackoverflow

Comment: It's not bad if you have to overwrite more specific styles, and it's not really bad in CSS, but in a jQuery selector it could cause some extra work, but it's not really bad there either.

Answer (score 0):

`.start li:first-child` overrides styling of `.change`

Change

```
.change{}
```

to

```
.start li.change{}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsAZQ/9/)